# "unexpected token: int" error on twitter4j program

Tags: java, twitter, arraylist, processing, twitter4j

Im using twitter4j 3.0.3, processing 2, and el capitan. I keep getting errors when trying to run this code! Particularly: `unexpected token: int` on the line `return (int) statuses.stream()`

I want that hashtag data to modify the color of the background to a shade of color in between red and green, depending on the number of #good and #bad tweets. I like to think of it as a +100/-100 spectrum. each #good tweet is +1, each #bad is -1. If it is at -100 tweets, then the ellipse is full red. If it is at +100 tweets, then the background is full green.

```
ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
Twitter twitterInstance;
Query queryForTwitter;

//ArrayList tweets;

void setup() {
  cb.setOAuthConsumerKey("xxxx");
  cb.setOAuthConsumerSecret("xxxx");
  cb.setOAuthAccessToken("xxxx");
  cb.setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("xxxx");
  cb.setUseSSL(true);

  size(640,440);

} //setup

//ArrayList<String> tweets = new ArrayList<String>();

public static void main (String args[]) throws TwitterException {
    Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
    List<Status> statuses = twitter.getUserTimeline("google");
    String hashtag = "#AlphaGo";
    System.out.println("The Twitter page contains " 
                        + countTweets(hashtag, statuses) 
                        + " tweets with the hashtag : " + hashtag);

}

public static int countTweets(String hashtag, List<Status> statuses){
    return (int) statuses.stream()
                         .filter(x -> x.getText().contains(hashtag))
                         .count();
}

//create a function that counts the tweets
//that contain a certain hashtag
int countTweets(String hashtag){
  int total = 0;
  for(String tweet : tweets){
    if(tweet.contains(hashtag)){
      total++;
    }
  }
  return total;
}

void draw(){

  //count the good and bad tweets
  int goodTweets = countTweets("#good");
  int badTweets = countTweets("#bad");

  //calculate color based on tweet counts
  float r = badTweets/100.0 * 255;
  float g = goodTweets/100.0 * 255;
  float b = 0;

  background(r, g, b);

}
```

The code has problems here:

```
public static void main (String args[]) throws TwitterException {
    Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
    List<Status> statuses = twitter.getUserTimeline("google");
    String hashtag = "#AlphaGo";
    System.out.println("The Twitter page contains " 
                        + countTweets(hashtag, statuses) 
                        + " tweets with the hashtag : " + hashtag);

}

public static int countTweets(String hashtag, List<Status> statuses){
    return (int) statuses.stream()
                         .filter(x -> x.getText().contains(hashtag))
                         .count();
}
```

Comment: How are you editing this code? Are you using the Processing editor, or are you using an IDE like eclipse? I also don't see any import statements. Please post an [mcve] that shows what you're actually running.

Comment: Im editing with the processing editor. I added an edit to the question so that it is more clear, hopefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a couple things wrong:

First, **Processing doesn't support Java 8 syntax.** This is Java 8 syntax:

```
statuses.stream().filter(x -> x.getText().contains(hashtag)).count();
```

You have to refactor this to use a basic for loop, which is in the code I gave you in your other question. Actually you already have a function that uses that, so I don't know why you've added this Java 8 function. Then again, you never declare the `tweets` variable that you use in that function.

Secondly, **Processing never calls the `main()` method.** You have to get rid of that method and move any of its code to a function that's actually called, like the `setup()` function.

Third, **you don't have any import statements**. I assume you've simply omitted them from your post, but don't make us guess. In the future, try to post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows exactly what you're running instead.

Comment: Thanks again for the quick response. That is all of my code that I have up there. I didnt omit anything for this post. How close am I to getting this code to work? I am about to give up and drop the class because i am so frustrated trying to get this to work...
The reason I have the Java 8 syntax stuff is because I was trying to change the hardcoded strings to pull data from twitter instead.

Comment: @zack.gray.ou You're very close. Please don't give up. I mentioned the import statements because I don't think your code will compile without them. Basically, you need to tell Processing where to be able to find classes like `ConfigurationBuilder` and `Status`, since they're in the Twitter4J library. You do that by importing those classes.